# Resetting Default Shortcut Keys in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, 22.04, gnome-terminal, default

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my VirtualBox VM and accidently messed up my terminal's shortcut key binds and now I wanted to reset it to the default settings. I found no visible option to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open **dconf Editor** (`dconf-editor`).

Go to **/ org / gnome / terminal / legacy**.

*Directly* right-click on **keybindings** and select **Reset recursively**.

Or, you can go into **keybindings** and look for a binding that has a pencil () on its left, right-click on it, and select **Set to default**.

Answer (score 2):

From command-line ... Simply run in the terminal:

```bash
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/
```

To reset all terminal shortcuts back to their original default key bindings.